# Android Unit Testing with Mockito for External REST API calls

Tags: android, junit, mockito, retrofit2, android-testing

I am new to JUnit test cases in Android. I heard that by using Mockito we can achieve easily.

My Android Class makes an external call to a REST API Service (Retrofit) that returns a JSON response. I have to mock that response (hardcoded JSON) and write test cases.

Please share your idea how to achieve this.

i am able to achieve.

updating with a piece of code.

```
class GenerateTripViewModelTest {

    @Mock
    private lateinit var mockRepository: GenerateTripRepository

    private val schedulerProvider = SchedulerProvider(Schedulers.trampoline(), Schedulers.trampoline())

    private lateinit var generateTripViewModel: GenerateTripViewModel
    
    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        generateTripViewModel = GenerateTripViewModel(mockRepository, schedulerProvider)
    }

    @Test
    fun SearchSuccessCase() {
        val tripReq = GenerateTripReqModel(ArrayList<String>(),"123","xxxx","xxxx")

        Mockito.`when`(mockRepository.generateTrip(tripReq)).thenReturn(Observable.just(GenerateTripResModel("")))

        val testObserver = TestObserver<GenerateTripResModel>()

        generateTripViewModel.generateTrip(tripReq).subscribe(testObserver)

        testObserver.assertNoErrors()
    }
```

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

```
class GenerateTripViewModel @Inject constructor(private val generateTripRepository: GenerateTripRepository,private val schedulerProvider: SchedulerProvider) : ViewModel() {
    
    fun generateTrip(reqModel: GenerateTripReqModel) = generateTripRepository.generateTrip(reqModel) 
}
```

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

```
@Singleton
class GenerateTripRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val apiServices: ApiServices, private val context: Context,
    private val appExecutors: AppExecutors = AppExecutors()) {

    /**
     * Generate Trip
     */
    fun generateTrip(reqModel: GenerateTripReqModel): Observable<GenerateTripResModel> = apiServices.generateTrip(reqModel)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Test{
        @Mock
        lateinit var redditApiService: RedditApiService
        lateinit var postSettingsViewModel: PostSettingsViewModel

        @Before
        fun setUp() {
            initMocks(this)
            postSettingsViewModel = PostSettingsViewModel(redditApiService, userRepo)
        }


        @Test
        fun testApi(){
            Mockito.`when`(redditApiService.getSubreddits("asd")).thenReturn(Single
                .just<SubredditResponse>(SubredditResponse(listOf(Subreddit("first")))))
           //make your tests

        }

    }
```

You can use viewmodel or presenter and pass your api service there. With mockito you can specify function call and its return value. `Mockito.when(api.get()).thenReturn(new Result())`.

Comment: can you describe more, unable to understand your piece of code.

Comment: if possible can you share related samples or articles.

Answer (score 1):

You can check google samples: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/test/java/com/android/example/github/api/GithubServiceTest.kt

You can use product flavors for mock your response or user MockWebServer library or replace your retrofit interface with you implementation what return json from assets

upd: I misunderstood the question. I agree with Phowner Biring